# Optimizing hash table implementation to accommodate large amount of elements

Tags: javascript, performance, hashtable

Consider the following scenario:

One million clients visit a store and pay an amount of money using their credit card. The credit card codes are generated using a 16-digit number, and replacing 4 of its digits (randomly) with the characters `'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'`. The 16-digit number is generated randomly once, and is used for every credit card, the only change between cards being the positions in the string of the aforementioned characters (that's ~40k possible distinct codes).

I have to organize the clients in a hash table, using a hash function of my choosing and also using open addressing (linear probing) to deal with the collisions. Once organized in the table, I have to find the client who

- paid the most money during his purchases.
- visited the store the most times.

My implementation of the hash table is as follows, and seems to be working correctly for the test of 1000 clients. However once I increase the number of clients to 10000 the page never finishes loading. This is a big issue since the total number of "shopping sessions" has to be one million, and I am not even getting close to that number.

```
class HashTable{

constructor(size){
    this.size = size;
    this.items = new Array(this.size);
    this.collisions = 0;
}

put(k, v){
    let hash = polynomial_evaluation(k);

    //evaluating the index to the array
    //using modulus a prime number (size of the array)
    //This works well as long as the numbers are uniformly
    //distributed and sparse.
    let index = hash%this.size;

    //if the array position is empty
    //then fill it with the value v.
    if(!this.items[index]){
        this.items[index] = v;
    }
    //if not, search for the next available position
    //and fill that with value v.
    //if the card already is in the array,
    //update the amount paid.
    //also increment the collisions variable.
    else{
        this.collisions++;
        let i=1, found = false;
        //while the array at index is full
        //check whether the card is the same,
        //and if not then calculate the new index.
        while(this.items[index]){
            if(this.items[index] == v){
                this.items[index].increaseAmount(v.getAmount());
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            index = (hash+i)%this.size;
            i++;
        }
        if(!found){
            this.items[index] = v;
        }

        found = false;
    }

    return index;
}

get(k){

    let hash = polynomial_evaluation(k);
    let index = hash%this.size, i=1;

    while(this.items[index] != null){
        if(this.items[index].getKey() == k){
            return this.items[index];
        }
        else{
            index  = (hash+i)%this.size;
            i++;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

findBiggestSpender(){
    let max = {getAmount: function () {
        return 0;
    }};

    for(let item of this.items){
        //checking whether the specific item is a client
        //since many of the items will be null
        if(item instanceof Client){
            if(item.getAmount() > max.getAmount()){
                max = item;
            }
        }

    }


    return max;
}

findMostFrequentBuyer(){

    let max = {getTimes: function () {
        return 0;
    }};

    for(let item of this.items){
        //checking whether the specific item is a client
        //since many of the items will be null
        if(item instanceof Client){
            if(item.getTimes() > max.getTimes()){
                max = item;
            }
        }

    }

    return max;
}
}
```

To key I use to calculate the index to the array is a list of 4 integers ranging from 0 to 15, denoting the positions of `'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'` in the string

Here's the hash function I am using:

```
function polynomial_evaluation(key, a=33){

//evaluates the expression:
// x1*a^(d-1) + x2*a^(d-2) + ... + xd
//for a given key in the form of a tuple (x1,x2,...,xd)
//and for a nonzero constant "a".
//for the evaluation of the expression horner's rule is used:
// x_d + a*(x_(d-1) + a(x_(d-2) + .... + a*(x_3 + a*(x_2 + a*x1))... ))

//defining a new key with the elements of the
//old times 2,3,4 or 5 depending on the position
//this helps for "spreading" the values of the keys

let nKey = [key[0]*2, key[1]*3, key[2]*4, key[3]*5];

let sum=0;

for(let i=0; i<nKey.length; i++){
    sum*=a;
    sum+=nKey[i];
}

return sum;
}
```

The values corresponding to the keys generated by the hash function are instances of a `Client` class which contains the fields `amount` (the amount of money paid), `times` (the times this particular client shopped), `key` (the array of 4 integers mentioned above), as well as getter functions for those fields. In addition there's a method that increases the `amount` when the same client appears more than once.

The size of the hash table is `87383` (a prime number) and the code in my main file looks like this:

```
//initializing the clients array
let clients = createClients(10000);
//creating a new hash table
let ht = new HashTable(N);

for(let client of clients){
    ht.put(client.getKey(), client);
}
```

This keeps running until google chrome gives a "page not responding" error. Is there any way I can make this faster? Is my approach on the subject (perhaps even my choice of language) correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @RandyCasburn What are you suggesting i should fix in my question? Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Have you debugged your script to see where it keeps hanging? Are you getting too many collisions?

Comment: Looks like homework...if it is, you should start by disclosing that. Anyway, you `while()` loop in your `put()` method is unlikely ever to resolve a modulus of zero (== false).

Comment: @Bergi I am ashamed to admit I have never used a debugger before and I am unsure of how it works... In the 1000 case there were 14 collisions.

Comment: @VlassisFo Then now is a good time to learn it :-) https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/ (assuming you use a Chromium-based browser)

Comment: @RandyCasburn I'm not sure i understand what you meant :/ If the result of the modulo operation is 0, shouldn't the `items` at index 0 be checked and continue from there?

Comment: Impossible to tell what `index = (hash+i)%this.size;` will result in given your code sample. You can ignore my comment. But I will say that as a general rule we should avoid `while()` & `do...while()` while relying on dynamic type conversions or other non-determinate logic tests. Use `for` loops and avoid all the infinite loop issues.

Answer (score 0):

The page is not responding since the main (UI) thread is locked. Use a WebWorker or ServiceWorker to handle the calculations, and post them as messages to the main thread.

Regarding optimizing your code, one thing I see is in `findBiggestSpender`. I'll break it down line-by-line.

```
let max = {getAmount: function () {
  return 0;
}};
```

This is a waste. Just assign a local variable, no need to keep calling `max.getAmount()` in every iteration.

`for(let item of this.items){`
The fastest way to iterate a list in Javascript is with a cached length for loop: `for (let item, len = this.items.length; i < len; i ++)`

`if(item instanceof Client){`

This is slower than a hard null check, just use `item !== null`.

Comment: Those are some nice suggestions, I'll try them right away and give you feedback as soon as I can. Thank you :)

Comment: Silly me did not realize that the `findBiggestSpender` and `findMostFrequentBuyer` functions are not called when the page is opened. That's because i expected to test them in the console after the hash table is finished constructing itself. Fixing the for loops didn't seem to have much effect on the performance either.  Thank you for your suggestions though.